# Get property that the operator was invoked for

Tags: python, add-on, development

Operators like `anim.keyframe_insert_button` can be invoked by right clicking a property or hovering over a property and hitting I. How does the operator know which property it's being invoked for?
Can I make an operator that works the same way?

What I need it for:

I'm displaying animated properties of an object from other scene (call it a sub-scene). The value displayed in the main scene depends on the current frame of the sub-scene. I am able to sync that an show the correct value but all the Blender's keyframe utilities depend on the main scene's current frame. I need to override keyframe related operators to adjust for the strip offset and scene's current frame.

Comment: `keyframe_insert_button` is [implemented in C](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/src/commit/a8819481cb4293484116a9aa8637907cd110e63c/source/blender/editors/animation/keyframing.c#L2675-L2679). It gets it by calling `UI_context_active_but_prop_get`. I don't know if there's a Python equivalent.

Comment: You can call `bpy.ops.ui.copy_data_path_button(full_path=True)` in your operator and then read `bpy.context.window_manager.clipboard`, but that's reeeeally ugly -_-

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/314103/185343 [bpy.context.property](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html#bpy.context.property) was added in Blender 4.0 and lets you know which property was clicked or hovered.