# Using python "getattr" to find out what button is right clicked (e.g. "X Rotation") returns an array when I need a single property

Tags: python, operator

As per Blender's [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Menu.html) about extending the right click context menu, I can find what UI button was right clicked with a custom operator I added to the menu:

[image: blender custom right click menu]

However, "button_prop" just outputs the entire Rotation vector array, like this:

[image: console output]

But the context menu knows I clicked the "X" Rotation field/button:

[image]

I don't see a way to access that data. **If I click X Rotation, I want to access just that property with this operation, not the entire array**

I can find the object this field points to, from the same Blender docs example:

```
value = getattr(context, "button_pointer", None)
```

But that just returns an Object, and not the specific property I clicked.

Here's my complete script:

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
    
# Right Click menu

class WM_OT_test_right_click_menu(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.test_right_click_menu"
    bl_label = "Test Right Click"

    def execute(self, context):
        
        #get name of right clicked custom prop
        pointer = getattr(context, "button_pointer", None) 
        prop = getattr(context, "button_prop", None)   
        
        print()
        print()
        print(prop)

        return {'FINISHED'}
     
def draw_button_menu(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.separator()
    layout.operator("wm.test_right_click_menu")
    

classes = [
    WM_OT_test_right_click_menu,
]        
        
      
def register():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(c)
    
    bpy.types.UI_MT_button_context_menu.append(draw_button_menu)


def unregister():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)
    
    bpy.types.UI_MT_button_context_menu.remove(draw_button_menu)
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Update (1-17-2024):
In rooting through Blender's [source code](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/9c0bffcc89f174f160805de042b00ae7c201c40b/source/blender/editors/animation/drivers.cc#L1100), I can see that, for example, the *Edit Driver* operator in the right click menu has the same setup as my "getattr" function:

```
UI_context_active_but_prop_get(C, &ptr, &prop, &index);
```

It has the context, pointer, and property. But *also* has the index, which I'm assuming is the index of the array when you click a button that's an array (location, rotation, scale, etc).

So I'm still not sure how to get the array index, but I can see evidence for this functionality in the source code.

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshot. Post the code instead.

Comment: I've pasted my script at the bottom of my post now.

Answer (score 1):

With Blender 4.0, they've added `context.property` that does exactly what I was asking for here. So, the problem is solved!

Here's some sample code. This adds an operator (menu item) to the right click menu called *Test Operator*. When clicked, *Test Operator* outputs the property you clicked, (e.g. 'scale') and the array index, to the system console. In my test case, output looked like this: (`bpy.data.objects['Cube.002'], 'scale', 0`)

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context


class OBJECT_OT_test_operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "agt.test_operator"
    bl_label = "Test Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
    def execute(self, context):
              
        print(context.property)

        return {'FINISHED'}

# Menu entries to add
  
def draw_button_menu(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.separator()
    layout.operator("agt.test_operator")

    
classes = [
    OBJECT_OT_test_operator
]   
    
def register():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(c) 
    
    bpy.types.UI_MT_button_context_menu.prepend(draw_button_menu)   

def unregister():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)
        
    bpy.types.UI_MT_button_context_menu.prepend(draw_button_menu)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```